# Node js crashes with native exception

Tags: node.js

I am getting unexpected exits (exit code 1) - and stalls ie promises never fulfilled - in a node application. Most of the times this happens, there is no error visible, however, I have seen the following stack trace on one occasion:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: fixed_size_above_fp + (stack_slots * kSystemPointerSize) - CommonFrameConstants::kFixedFrameSizeAboveFp + outgoing_size == result.
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffeefbfc9e0
 1: 0x100120e62 node::NodePlatform::GetStackTracePrinter()::$_3::__invoke() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x10103af53 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x10030a633 v8::internal::Deoptimizer::Deoptimizer(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::JSFunction, v8::internal::DeoptimizeKind, unsigned int, unsigned long, int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x10030839e v8::internal::Deoptimizer::New(unsigned long, v8::internal::DeoptimizeKind, unsigned int, unsigned long, int, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x34a8fad8216d 
 6: 0x1006c5e23 v8::internal::NativeRegExpMacroAssembler::Execute(v8::internal::String, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, int*, int, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::JSRegExp) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x1006c5d66 v8::internal::NativeRegExpMacroAssembler::Match(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int*, int, int, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x1006d22ad v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExecRaw(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, int*, int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x1006d2967 v8::internal::RegExpGlobalCache::FetchNext() [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x100725666 v8::internal::Runtime_RegExpExecMultiple(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x100a81fb9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x100ad1c5a Builtins_RegExpReplace [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x100a72e52 Builtins_StringPrototypeReplace [/usr/local/bin/node]
```

I'm not sure quite what to make of this, as the exits appear to happen at different points. Does the above seem likely to be a memory problem?